# Does nodejs v0.8.18 https support TLS1.2

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I am on nodejs v0.8.18 and implemented a server using https module. Does this version of nodejs support TLS1.2 protocol? If not what needs to be done to make sure my server is on TLS1.2 protocol.

Comment: Why are you still using v0.8?

Comment: I have implemented the server quite a while ago and did not have any reason to update. But I have a need to make the server use TLS1.2 protocol. Can update my server if latest versions support TLS1.2.